# Serialize class to XML, dynamically set element name based on property, xmltext based on other property

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, serialization, visual-studio-2013, xml-serialization

Is it possible to serialize the class below to XML, and generate this output?

The challenge is that the element doc_id and client_name should be dynamically set based on the key (in this case doc_id and client_name). The corresponding value should be placed in the text of the element (in this case 1, Client 1, 12, and Client 2).

I can rewrite the classes, but I have to generate this XML.

```
<row>
  <doc_id>00000001</doc_id>
  <client_name>Client 1</client_name>
</row>
<row>
  <doc_id>000000012</doc_id>
  <client_name>Client 2</client_name>
</row>

    public struct SerializableKeyValuePair<T1, T2>
    {
        public T1 Key;

        public T2 Value;

        public SerializableKeyValuePair(T1 key, T2 value)
        {
            Key = key;
            Value = value;
        }
    }

    public class ActionParameter
    {
    [XmlElement("Row")]
        public List<SerializableKeyValuePair<object, object>> Rows;
    }
```

Comment: Not really. You'll need to handle writing/reading manually if you are wanting to customize the structure like that. Even if you could, I would think it would be practically impossible for the serializer to know how to deserialize it back.

Comment: disappointing... but makes sense. do you want to post that as the answer

Comment: Added an answer. I meant to do this the other day and completely forgot. Better late than never!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot without writing your own serializer or just handling the reading/writing manually.

Trying to use a pre-made serializer just won't work because there is no way for it to know what is actually the *key* and what is the *value*.

However, it is a possibility to still use this in combination with the standard `XmlSerializer`.

```
public class ActionParameter
{
    [XmlElement("Row")]
    public List<XmlElement> RowElements
    {
        // The `get` is purely for the serializer. No reason for you to call it.
        get { return SomeMethodToSerializeToXmlDoc(Rows).ChildNodes.OfType<XmlElement>()
                                                                   .ToList(); }
        // The `set` from the Serializer will allow your "Rows" to be Deserialized.
        set { DeserializeKeyValues(value); }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public List<SerializableKeyValuePair<string, string>> Rows { get; set; }

    void DeserializeKeyValues(List<XmlElement> elements) 
    {
         Rows = new List<SerializableKeyValuePair<string, string>>();
         foreach(XmlElement element in elements)
         {
             // Shouldn't your List of Rows, actually be another List of Key Values?
             // This call won't actually work. I think you need to really
             // loop through the children of this element as your key values.
             Rows.Add(new SerializableKeyValuePair<string, string>(element));
         }
    }
}
```

```
public struct SerializableKeyValuePair<T1, T2>
{
    public T1 Key;

    public T2 Value;

    public SerializableKeyValuePair(T1 key, T2 value)
    {
        Key = key;
        Value = value;
    }

    public SerializableKeyValuePair(XmlElement element)
    {
        Key = element.LocalName;
        var textNode = element.SelectSingleNode("text()");
        // Here you are also not limited to just text, since you have an actual Element, 
        // you could attempt to try and implement deserializing custom classes/objects.
        if (textNode != null)
            Value = SomeConvertForT2(textNode.Value);
    }
}
```

This is basically pseudo code I quickly whipped up to show you one way of possibly doing it.